# finding total and unique hits for each product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure as follows

```
    id            productid             ip               hittime
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1                5               1.1.1.1           2011-05-03 06:55:11
     2                5               1.1.1.1           2011-05-03 06:57:11
     3                6               2.2.2.2           2011-05-03 07:30:00
     4                4               1.1.1.1           2011-05-03 07:32:54
     5                5               2.2.2.2           2011-05-03 07:55:00
```

Now I need query such that, it output me total and unique hits for each product

```
     productid              totalhits                uniquehits
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        4                       1                        1
        5                       3                        2
        6                       1                        1
```

Criteria for

Total Hits = all the records that belong to particular product

Unique Hits = 2 hits are identified as unique hits if (1) IP is different or (2) for same ip, there is difference of 5 mins in hittime

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try and didn't work?

Comment: I tried, I was able to find count for a specific product (total hits) and wasn't able to find unique hits

Comment: SELECT productid, count(ip) as totalhits FROM product_hits group by productid

Comment: why the unique hits of productid 4 is 2 and totalhits is 1 ?

Comment: It was my mistake, typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rMX was extremely close with his solution, it's quite clever. He should really get the credit, I just tweaked it slightly to add in a couple missing pieces:

```
select productid, count(*) totalhits, 
    count(distinct 
        concat(ip,
            date_format(hittime, '%Y%m%d%H'),
            round(date_format(hittime, '%i') / 5) * 5)
        ) uniquehits
from table
group by productid
```

Changes I made to rMX's idea:

1. Changed ceil() to round() because
   ceil/floor will cause edge cases to
   be treated improperly
2. Multiply the results of the round()
   by 5. I think rMX meant to do this
   and just forgot to type it.

**EDIT:** The multiplying by 5 really isn't necessary. My brain was just muddled. Changing ceil() to round() still matters though.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD>**

```
select productid, count(*) totalhits, 
    count(distinct 
        concat(ip,
            date_format(hittime, '%Y%m%d%H'),
            ceil(date_format(hittime, '%i') / 5))
        ) uniquehits
from table
group by productid
```

I think, this should work. Sorry, had no time to test it.

Comment: Nope, this won't work either. Please check requirement for unique hits. I have mentioned in question.

Comment: @I-M-JM: Even though you *have* specified that in your post, it would be much better if you modified your sample output to illustrate that. People often see the example and assume they get it *from the example* without paying much attention to the rest of the post (which is wrong, but they are mere humans and they might have other things to do and thus want to be quick).